# how to count with more than 1 having clause mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

i have 1 table called order_star_member, which contain createdAt as the date of the transaction, users_id as the buyer, total_price_star_member as the amount of the transaction. on this case i want to find out buyer who had star member (transaction in a month within >= 600000) and find out where they coming from, the data(dummy) for order_star_member begin on January 2019 untill March 2019

```
    CREATE TABLE order_star_member  ( users_id INT, 
                                       createdAt DATE, 
                                       total_price_star_member DECIMAL(10,2) );
INSERT INTO order_star_member  VALUES
(12,'2019-01-01',100000),
(12,'2019-01-10',100000),
(12,'2019-01-20',100000),
(12,'2019-02-10',100000),
(12,'2019-02-15',300000),
(12,'2019-02-21',500000),
(13,'2019-01-02',900000),
(13,'2019-01-11',300000),
(13,'2019-01-18',400000),
(13,'2019-02-06',100000),
(13,'2019-02-08',900000),
(13,'2019-02-14',400000),
(14,'2019-01-21',500000),
(14,'2019-01-23',200000),
(14,'2019-01-24',300000),
(14,'2019-02-08',100000),
(14,'2019-02-09',200000),
(14,'2019-02-14',100000),
(15, '2019-03-04',1000000),
(14, '2019-03-04', 300000),
(14, '2019-03-04', 350000),
(13, '2019-03-04', 400000),
(15, '2019-01-23', 620000),
(15, '2019-02-01', 650000),
(12, '2019-03-03', 750000),
(16, '2019-03-04', 650000),
(17, '2019-03-03', 670000),
(18, '2019-02-02', 450000),
(19, '2019-03-03', 750000);
SELECT * from order_star_member;
```

and then i summarize data per month

```
-- summary per-month data
SELECT users_id, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'January' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_January,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'February' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_February,
        SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'March' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_March
FROM order_star_member 
GROUP BY users_id
ORDER BY 1;
```

on this case i want to find out the distribution for each star member (users_id who transaction >= 600000 in a month) in march and where the users_Id doing his transaction >= 600.000 before march (if the users_Id doing transaction on the first time in march, then the users_Id enter the march to march statistic)

```
expected results for star member on month march statistics

    +-------------------+------+-------+
    | count star_member | year | month |  
    +-------------------+------+-------+
    |                 2 | 2019 |     1 |  
    |                 1 | 2019 |     2 |  
    |                 3 | 2019 |     3 |  
    +-------------------+------+-------+
```

explanation : there's 2 users_Id who become star_member on march (users_Id 14,15) and become his first star_member on january 2019,
there's 1 users_id who become star_member on march (users_id 12) and become his first star_member on february 2019,
and there's 3 users_id who become star_member on march (users_id 16, 17, 19) and become his first star_member on march 2019

this is my progress syntax so far

```
select count(osm.users_id) as count_buyer, year(osm.createdAt) as year,
month(osm.createdAt) as month
 from order_star_member osm
WHERE osm.createdAt >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(osm.createdAt), 1) 
+ INTERVAL month(osm.createdAt) month- INTERVAL 1 month AND
 osm.createdAt <= MAKEDATE(YEAR(osm.createdAt), 1)
 + INTERVAL month(osm.createdAt) month- INTERVAL 1 day group by users_Id
 having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000
 AND 
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from order_star_member osm2
 WHERE osm2.users_id = osm.users_id 
 AND osm2.createdAt < MAKEDATE(YEAR(osm.createdAt), 1) + 
 INTERVAL month(osm.createdAt) month - INTERVAL 1 month
 group by users_id 
 having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000)
 AND 
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 from order_star_member osm3
 where
 osm3.users_id = osm.users_id AND
 osm3.createdAt >= '2019-03-01' AND
 osm3.createdAt < '2019-04-01' group by users_id
 having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000)
 group by year(osm.createdAt), month(osm.createdAt);
```

here's the fiddle 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d642774357900f967d7af9659d8639d7

Comment: i forgot to edit the explanation, im sorry, now im just edited it

Comment: Hmm... `users_id=13` is NOT counted because he is NOT starred in March???

Comment: yes, because i want to make statistic on month march, and users_id 13 not counted because they not being star member on march (transaction >= 600000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 users_id, 
                 DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') year_and_month,
                 SUM(total_price_star_member) OVER (PARTITION BY users_id, DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m')) month_price
          FROM order_star_member ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT users_id, MIN(year_and_month) year_and_month
          FROM cte1
          WHERE month_price >= 600000
          GROUP BY users_id )
SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
       year_and_month DIV 100 `year`,
       year_and_month MOD 100 `month`
FROM cte2
GROUP BY year_and_month
ORDER BY `year`, `month`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48fffb91d2a091feee4cc8957df189ab)

---

> What is your MySQL server version? – Akina
>
> it's 5.7.23-log – Fachry Dzaky Al-Qadri Sabil

```sql
SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
       year_and_month DIV 100 `year`,
       year_and_month MOD 100 `month`
FROM (SELECT users_id, 
             MIN(year_and_month) year_and_month
      FROM ( SELECT users_id, 
                    DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') year_and_month,
                    SUM(total_price_star_member) month_price
             FROM order_star_member
             GROUP BY users_id, 
                      DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') 
             HAVING month_price >= 600000 ) starrings
      GROUP BY users_id ) first_starrings
GROUP BY year_and_month
ORDER BY `year`, `month`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5d2a17c1ce9f8201e35ec93b294d32a4)

---

> expected results for star member on month march statistics

...

> Hmm... users_id=13 is NOT counted because he is NOT starred in March??? – Akina
>
> yes, because i want to make statistic on month march, and users_id 13 not counted because they not being star member on march (transaction >= 600000) – Fachry Dzaky Al-Qadri Sabil

As I understand the user counted in this statistic MUST be starred in this month. If so

```sql
SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
       year_and_month DIV 100 `year`,
       year_and_month MOD 100 `month`
FROM (SELECT users_id, 
             MIN(year_and_month) year_and_month
      FROM ( SELECT users_id, 
                    DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') year_and_month,
                    SUM(total_price_star_member) month_price
             FROM order_star_member
             GROUP BY users_id, 
                      DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') 
             HAVING month_price >= 600000 ) starrings
      GROUP BY users_id
      HAVING SUM(year_and_month = '201903') > 0 ) first_starrings
GROUP BY year_and_month
ORDER BY `year`, `month`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=673d7b68a8244db10725b8160692fd2b)

Comment: im sure you are the pro in mysql ahahha because i didnt understand what your code, let me learn it, what makes me confuse is the expected results are the statistic of march, what if i want to find out the statistic of the february (based on the data dummy), so the results are 2 from month 1 2019, and 1 from month 2 2019

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil *i didnt understand what your code* Look at the fiddle - I comments some explainations. Try to execute it partially (`WITH cte1 AS (...) SELECT * FROM cte1`, then `WITH cte1 AS (...), cte2 AS (...) SELECT * FROM cte2`) and compare the comment and the result. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=515bdc2c722b5339a5d98ee002fe0651).

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil *what if i want to find out the statistic of the february (based on the data dummy)* Add according WHERE into `cte1`, remove all records above the month in interest.

Comment: anyway, when i try in my real data, it's called error code 1064, you have an error in you sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte1 as (SELECT DISTINCT users_id, DATE_FORM' at line 3

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil ??? What is your MySQL server version?

Comment: it's 5.7.23-log sir @Akina

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil ??? If so why you post the fiddle used MySQL version 8 ??? My solution is not applicable to version 5+.

Comment: OMG IM SORRY SIR, im new on mysql fiddle and i just dont realize that, can you just reanswer my question with your new question :( @Akina

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil The solution applicable to your MySQL version added. The logic is absolutely the same.

Comment: unfortunately sir your logic it seems to be wrong, what i want based on expected results are the statistic on star member in march which doing his first star member from january, and then star member in march which doing his first star member from february, and star member in march which doing his first star member from march itself. and your logic after i check it  based on your query are star member in january which doing first star member in january, and then february on first star member february, and march on first star member in march

Comment: accidentally, whether your logic and my logic in data dummy are same, so it's seems to be right but when im applied on my real data, it was little bit wrong

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil Test step-by-step and look for intermediate results, search for problematic values and acccording reason. Check for incorrect dates, wrong prices, non-existent users... look warnings if occured... set SQL mode to maximal strict regime and look for errors and warnings.

Comment: i've just updated the expected results and fiddle with your logic before and my logic different, so you can analyze it, im sorry for my mistakes before @Akina

Comment: omg this is what i want, thankyou very much from indonesia sir! @Akina