# count with more than 1 having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

so i have a case from my previous question [how to count with more than 1 having clause mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500057/how-to-count-with-more-than-1-having-clause-mysql)

assume i have the data dummy like this

```
CREATE TABLE order_star_member  ( users_id INT, 
                                       createdAt DATE, 
                                       total_price_star_member DECIMAL(10,2) );
INSERT INTO order_star_member  VALUES
(12,'2019-01-01',100000),
(12,'2019-01-10',100000),
(12,'2019-01-20',100000),
(12,'2019-02-10',100000),
(12,'2019-02-15',300000),
(12,'2019-02-21',500000),
(13,'2019-01-02',900000),
(13,'2019-01-11',300000),
(13,'2019-01-18',400000),
(13,'2019-02-06',100000),
(13,'2019-02-08',900000),
(13,'2019-02-14',400000),
(14,'2019-01-21',500000),
(14,'2019-01-23',200000),
(14,'2019-01-24',300000),
(14,'2019-02-08',100000),
(14,'2019-02-09',200000),
(14,'2019-02-14',100000),
(15, '2019-03-04',1000000),
(14, '2019-03-04', 300000),
(14, '2019-03-04', 350000),
(13, '2019-03-04', 400000),
(15, '2019-01-23', 620000),
(15, '2019-02-01', 650000),
(12, '2019-03-03', 750000),
(16, '2019-03-04', 650000),
(17, '2019-03-03', 670000),
(18, '2019-02-02', 450000),
(19, '2019-03-03', 750000);
SELECT * from order_star_member;
```

and then i summarize data per month

```
-- summary per-month data
SELECT users_id, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'January' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_January,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'February' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_February,
        SUM( CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'March' 
                 THEN total_price_star_member
                 END ) total_price_star_member_March
FROM order_star_member 
GROUP BY users_id
ORDER BY 1;
```

on my previous question i have a data called order_star_member, which contain createdAt as the date of the transaction, users_id as the buyer, total_price_star_member as the amount of the transaction. on this case i want to find out buyer who had star member (transaction in a month within >= 600000) and find out where they coming from, the data(dummy) for order_star_member begin on January 2019 untill March 2019 and it solved by @Akina with this query

```
SELECT COUNT(users_id) count_star_member,
       year_and_month DIV 100 `year`,
       year_and_month MOD 100 `month`
FROM (SELECT users_id, 
             MIN(year_and_month) year_and_month
      FROM ( SELECT users_id, 
                    DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') year_and_month,
                    SUM(total_price_star_member) month_price
             FROM order_star_member
             GROUP BY users_id, 
                      DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%Y%m') 
             HAVING month_price >= 600000 ) starrings
      GROUP BY users_id
      HAVING SUM(year_and_month = '201903') > 0 ) first_starrings
GROUP BY year_and_month
ORDER BY `year`, `month`;
```

explanation i want to find out the distribution for each star member (users_id who transaction >= 600000 in a month) in march and where the users_Id doing his transaction >= 600.000 before march (if the users_Id doing transaction on the first time in march, then the users_Id enter the march to march statistic)

but on april 2019 to be star member you have to transaction >= 700.000 instead of 600.000, so i want to find out the data for user where transaction in april 2019 with >= 700.000 (star member) in a month of april 2019 and doing first transaction before april 2019 with total amount of 600.000 in a month

so which part i should change in this query to find out the user who doing total transaction >= 700.000 in april in a month and doing his first  transaction (if first transaction before april) >= 600.000

Comment: It seems like kind of a lot.  Are you in a position to offload some of that logic to your server script or even a UDF?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: usually i used dbfiddle.uk to give some example data, but dbfiddle.uk was unable to use idk why

Comment: fiddle me this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c77f2/1

Comment: you can see on that fiddle it provided you the data buyer on march with the transaction >= 600000 on march and where the buyer doing first transaction with also >= 600.000

Comment: in april 2019, to be star member you should transaction >= 700.000 not in >= 600.000 again

Comment: so i want to find out the user who transaction before april 2019 in >= 600.000 in a month, but on april 2019 transaction in >= 700.000, how to make that

Comment: Yeah, I understand completely, no need to go over the details again,  I'm simply suggesting that there may be a better way to do this,  one that is more maintainable as it seems you evolving/adding to this query as time goes on, so this query is pretty darn slow as it stands, and the more you add to the complexity, you are going to be seeing some issues at high load possibly.   However, it's your code, do what you like.  :)

Comment: so can you just give a suggestion about this query so i can solve this problem?

Comment: hmm... ok well 1st add April to your monthly summary query.  Then add all the hairball logic into your other query.   It's not difficult as it is cumbersome,  you need more than that ?   You want me to actually write the hairball code for you that I'm not so subtly urging you to move away from...  I'm afraid I might be disinclined to acquiesce to such a request.  :)

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: And seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c77f2/1 this is my fiddle was made by @BrianPatterson, sorry im still didnt understand what's mean of handling issues of data display in application code